# Woocommerce Widget Product order by title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

My initial goal is to be able to display Woocommerce Products in the sidebar, **sorted by Title**. Currently the only sorting options in this widget are *Date, Price, Random and Sales.*

I was able to add the Title sorting option in 2 parts in **class-wc-widget-products.php**:

```
'orderby' => array(
                'type'  => 'select',
                'std'   => 'date',
                'label' => __( 'Order by', 'woocommerce' ),
                'options' => array(
                    'title'   => __( 'Title', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'date'   => __( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'price'  => __( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'rand'   => __( 'Random', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'sales'  => __( 'Sales', 'woocommerce' ),
                ),
```

And here:

```
switch ( $orderby ) {
    case 'title' :
        $query_args['orderby']  = 'title';
        break;
    case 'price' :
        $query_args['meta_key'] = '_price';
        $query_args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num';
        break;
    case 'rand' :
        $query_args['orderby']  = 'rand';
        break;
    case 'sales' :
        $query_args['meta_key'] = 'total_sales';
        $query_args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num';
        break;
    default :
        $query_args['orderby']  = 'date';
}
```

This customization works fine, but:

**My question:** where should I save this customized "`class-wc-widget-products.php`" file preventing it from being overwritten at the next Woocommerce update? 
**OR...** is there a more elegant way to accomplish this? Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Kindly, making what you have done **is something really to avoid. 
>
>   It's prohibited for developers** *(so I had to rename the title of your question)*.
>
> ***First inconvenient*** (as you already know): you loose your changes when plugin is updated.
>
> **Nobody override core files…** So please remove all your changes or get the original file back.
>
> That is why [**actions and filters exist**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/) all through the code

The correct way to force **`orderby`** by **"title"** can be done this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_widget_query_args','title_orderby_products_widget_query_arg', 10, 1 );
function title_orderby_products_widget_query_arg( $query_args ) {
    // set 'title' for orderby 
    $query_args['orderby'] = 'title';

    return $query_args;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This should work for you.

> Then you can [**add some conditions**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) to better target this...

---

Official documentation: [WooCommerce Action and Filter Hook Reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html)